# Fetch request that returns a coredata URL. Why? and how to access the managed Object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I had to perform a "complex" fetch request to achieve a `group by` operation. 
In this request I need to obtain 2 values, one of these is a relationship, not a property.

Here the code to create this request:

```
// Create the request

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Entry"];


// Create Sum Expression

NSExpression *ex = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:"
                                             arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:   
                                                       [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"amount"]]];
NSExpressionDescription *ed = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];

[ed setName:@"totalAmount"];
[ed setExpression:ex];
[ed setExpressionResultType:NSInteger64AttributeType];


// Add properties and group by

[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[ed,THERELATIONSHIP]]; // properties
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType]; // result type
[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:THERELATIONSHIP];    // group by
```

By this request I correctly obtain the `NSExpression` value grouped by `THERELATIONSHIP`.  With the fetched Request this relationship is expressed **with an URL** (I suppose that's because I forced the result to be an NSDictionary through `setResultType. 
**Question 1:** could you confirm that this theory is correct?)

The URL has this format:

```
0x8db2c60 <x-coredata://F1C06CE8-E610-4207-A388-1FDB8FFA8A2F/THERELATIONSHIP/p1>
```

**Question 2:** How can I access the ManagedObject from this URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:` on the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to convert the URI into an `NSManagedObjectID`. Once you have the managed object ID you can then use `objectRegisteredForID:` on the `NSManagedObjectContext`.